# Avoiding an empty catch clause

Tags: javascript, try-catch-finally

I have a function which checks to see if the user has made any changes, and if so, warns them of this fact. When they choose to discard their changes, I have another function which a) restores the state to pre-edit, and b) updates a global object which holds info about the current edit (including whether one exists).

What I *don't* want to happen is that some error is thrown on trying to remove the edit box elements, and as a result the system doesn't update the global object flag or show the hidden pre-edit elements. If this happens, the program may think an edit is still going on when it isn't, leaving the user trapped in a "Discard changes?" cycle. For this reason, I catch any errors thrown in the destroy phase, and then show the hidden elements and update the global, like this:

```
function cancelEdit() {

    try {
        // destroy editing boxes
        // [code goes here]
    } catch(e) {
    } finally {
        // restore hidden elements
        // [code goes here]

        // update global edit cache object
        // [code goes here]

        // rethrow the error for analysis server-side
        if(window.onerror) window.onerror();
    }

}
```

Having an empty catch block like above seems like a code smell to me, but I don't think this way is necessarily better. (But maybe it is.)

```
function cancelEdit() {

    try {
        // destroy editing boxes
        // [code goes here]
    } catch(e) {
        cancelEditInternal();
        // rethrow the error for analysis server-side
        throw e;
    }

    cancelEditInternal();

}

function cancelEditInternal() {

    // restore hidden elements
    // [code goes here]

    // update global edit cache object
    // [code goes here]

}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a pattern that I'm neglecting... or is this just a consequence of the fact that I'm using try/catch/finally where it isn't usually used?

Comment: Whoops, I had a feeling I was overthinking it. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `finally` block:

```
function cancelEdit() {
    try {
        // destroy editing boxes
        // [code goes here]
    } finally {
        cancelEditInternal();
    }

}
```

The `finally` block will be executed whether or not the body of the `try` throws an error. (If you keep the `catch` clause, the `finally` block will still execute.)

Comment: I realized after seeing these responses that my model up above is flawed, since when `window.onerror` is called, it doesn't receive any arguments. Will a window.onerror get called if I don't have the catch block? (Or maybe even with a catch block?)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius - `window.onerror` will be called if the script generates an error. If you catch the error within the script, then neither `window.onerror` nor the default event handler will be called (unless you rethrow the error).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the `catch` block, then don't use it:

```
try {
    // destroy editing boxes
    // [code goes here]
} finally {
    // restore hidden elements
    // [code goes here]

    // update global edit cache object
    // [code goes here]

    // rethrow the error for analysis server-side
    if(window.onerror) window.onerror();
}
```

As you can see in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.14), a `try` statement consist of `try` followed by either `catch` or `finally` or both.